# Fractional part of $n!e$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the limit of $n \sin (2 \pi \cdot e \cdot n!)$ as $n$ goes to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/what-is-the-limit-of-n-sin-2-pi-cdot-e-cdot-n-as-n-goes-to-infinity)

In order to solve the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin2\pi n!e$$ . 
This question is very likely to have been asked.

I remember this question and the answer is like $2\pi$ or something .

I also do remember approximating $n!e$ but somehow i don't remember and can't figure out right now .

Comment: Is it $\sin(2 \pi n! e)$?  I would think so, but parentheses would be appreciated.

Comment: @Belgi: Huh? $ $

Comment: @Begi : I don't think that way it can be done or may be too hard .

Comment: My mistake, my comment was about " but somehow i don't remember", I thought the PO doesn't remember the approximation...

Comment: Nice problem, but I'd also like to see a different approach from the classical one.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the usual series for $e$. Then $n!e$ is an integer plus
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots.\tag{$1$}$$
The sum $(1)$ is bigger than $\frac{1}{n+1}$. 
It is less than
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots,$$
a geometric series with sum $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
n!e
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k!/n!}\\
&\equiv\frac1{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\dots\pmod{\mathbb{Z}}
\end{align}
$$
where the last sum is greater than $\frac1{n+1}$ yet less than $\frac1n=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^3}+\dots$

Thus, we have the bounds
$$
\frac1{n+1}<n!e-\lfloor n!e\rfloor<\frac1n
$$
Therefore,
$$
n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n+1}\right)<n\sin(2\pi n!e)<n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)
$$
and by the Squeeze Theorem, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi n!e)=2\pi
$$

Comment: One doubt that i have is that why are we not taking account of the integer that we get ? as $n\to \infty$ that can contribute a lot as well right ? so what am i still missing

Comment: @Theorem: $\sin(2\pi n+2\pi x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: Very silly of me. Thanks.

Comment: @robjohn: very detailed! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\mathrm e=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n1/k!+R_n$ with $R_n=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}1/k!$. Hence $n!\,\mathrm e$ equals an integer plus $n!R_n$. Now $1/(n+1)!\lt R_n\lt1/(n\,n!)$, hence $n!R_n=1/n+o(1/n)$, which is all the precision you need.