# How to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\sin(2\pi en!)=2\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

Please give me some hint to proceed. I'm clueless:

> Show that, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\sin(2\pi en!)=2\pi$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/what-is-the-limit-of-n-sin-2-pi-cdot-e-cdot-n-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}$, hence
$en!=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}+\frac1{n+1}+\ldots$ is quite close to an integer.