# Calculate $\lim \sin(2\pi n!e)$. [SOLVED]

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, exponential-function

I need to calculate $\lim \sin(2\pi n!e)$.

I put it into Wolfram and saw that it is likely to converge to 0.

Of course this would mean that the fractional part of $n!e$ should be always very close to either 0 or 0.5.

It means that the fluctuation of the fractional part is gonna decrease. But how do I show that it will stop around 0 or 0.5?

Cheers.

**EDIT: Solved.**

$n!e = k + \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\left( \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \ldots \right) < k + \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} + \ldots \right) = k + \frac{1}{n} $

where $k \in Z$

Therefore, the fractional part of $n!e$ approaches $0$.

Comment: What is n approaching in the limit?

Comment: The limit seems to be 0. The sequence is convergent, but I also need to prove it as well as calculate the limit.

Comment: Once again, what is the variable that you have approach a value. I assume it to be n. What value is n approaching? Is n approaching infinity?

Comment: Use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for $n!$.

Comment: How do you "see that the difference between (n+1)!e and n!e is: k+1/(n+1) for some integer k". The difference is (n+1)e, which is decidedly not rational.

Comment: Use Robert Israel's very useful hint. The "tail" is $\lt \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots\right)$.  This is a geometric series.

Comment: @Zach466920 what other limit could there be to consider? Limit for $2 \to -1$? :P

Comment: @Zardo well I know the limit is any number between -1 and 1 and that sin oscillates so as n approaches infinity, the limit tends to anything between -1 and 1 ;)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/what-is-the-limit-of-n-sin-2-pi-cdot-e-cdot-n-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Comment: @AndréNicolas, why is there (n+1)! in the denominator there? I recon it should be simply n+1. Then how does this help me? Read my edit :) Thanks!

Comment: You left out my $(n+1)!$ in the denominator. Let us look at  a particular example, $5!\left(\frac{1}{6!}+\frac{1}{7!}+\frac{1}{8!}+\frac{1}{9!}+\cdots\right)$. We have $\frac{1}{7!}\lt \frac{1}{6! \cdot 6}$. We have $\frac{1}{8!}\lt \frac{1}{6! \cdot 6^2}$. And so on. So the full sum is $\lt \frac{5!}{6!}(1+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\cdots)$. Sum the series and simplify.  We get $\frac{1}{5}$. In general we get that the tail is $\lt \frac{1}{n}$, which goes to $0$.

Comment: Yes, yes, sure Andre. Thanks for your thorough explanation, but I simply made a silly mistake during simplifying the expression.
I've done the same calculation properly now and proved that the tail approches 0. Thank you for your time and keep being a good person.

Comment: Another way: By the Lagrange form of the remainder, the tail $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots$ is  $\lt \frac{e^1}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, move the solution to an answer.

Comment: So I should post the answer myself and tick it? I'm new here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $n!\; e = (integer) + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n!/k!$

Comment: Ok, so I wrote this down (using Andre Nicolas' comment):

$n!\cdot \left( \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \ldots \right) < n!\cdot \left( \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \ldots \right) = \frac{(n-1)!}{n+1}$

I think the RHS thing is divergent though, so does this even help me? If not, could you give me another hint?

Comment: You've mistranscribed André Nicolas's comment: The tail is $n! \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots\right) = n!\left(\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+...\right) = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots < \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Oh jesus, of course I wrote total nonsense. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, now it makes more sense, the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

$n!e = k + \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\left( \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \ldots \right) < k + \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} + \ldots \right) = k + \frac{1}{n} $

where $k \in Z$

Therefore, the fractional part of $n!e$ approaches $0$.