# A limit of n times sine values at factorially spaced arguments

Tags: limits

Evaluate the following limit

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n \sin(2\pi \;e \;n!)$

I have no idea how to proceed forward?

Answer for above is $2\pi$ but I don't know how this comes about.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/what-is-the-limit-of-n-sin-2-pi-cdot-e-cdot-n-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Comment: For problems like this where you have $n!$ in the limit and $n\to\infty$, using Stirling's result helps most of the time.

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee  thanks i got it.

Comment: @ learner  ok thanks.