# $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2^n \pi \sqrt{e}\mathrm n!)=?$

Tags: limits

We know that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi \mathrm en!)=2\pi$$

now :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2^n  \pi \sqrt{e}\mathrm n!)=?$$

I tried:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your first "we know that..." line.

Comment: @SimpleArt :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/what-is-the-limit-of-n-sin-2-pi-cdot-e-cdot-n-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Comment: you have to bound the fractional part of the sequence inside sine...

Comment: Why does it have a limit? Doesn't it just oscillate indefinitely

Comment: The photo is not clear. Please typeset it.

Comment: Unless you type in what's in the photo, this is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is tweaked version of the Christian Blatter's answer on the link you posted(hence community wiki). $$2^{n-1}\sqrt{e}n!=2^nn!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2^k)k!}=2^{n-1}n!\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2^k)k!}+\sum_{k=n}^
\infty\frac{1}{(2^k)k!}\right)=m_{n-1}+r_{n-1}$$
With $m_{n-1}\in \Bbb{Z}$ and
$$\frac{1}{2n}<r_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}+\cdots<\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\cdots\right)<\frac{1}{2(n-1)}$$
Since
$$a_n=n\sin(2\pi\cdot2^{n-1} \sqrt{e}n!)=n\sin(2\pi r_{n-1})=n\ \ 2\pi r_{n-1}\frac{\sin(2\pi r_{n-1})}{2\pi r_{n-1}}$$
And $r_n\to 0$ it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}(nr_{n-1})=2\pi\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\pi$$

Comment: My method is wrong?

Comment: Why do you look at $2^{n-1}\sqrt e n!$?

Comment: @zhw. So I could remove $2\pi m_n$ as a period.

Comment: @Almot1960 I can't really figure out what's written,presumably I can understand first 3 lines but not what you did after.